# Lock implemention on "Class" class object for synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, jls, mutual-exclusion

I was going through [this link](http://www.artima.com/underthehood/thread2.html) . According to this :

> Class locks are actually implemented as object locks. When the JVM loads a class file, it creates an instance of class java.lang.Class. When you lock a class, you are actually locking that class's Class object.

But according to java spec , all objects of same type(class) on heap share single Class object.
So how can this be true for multi-thread synchronized access to Objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class lock

```
synchronized (String.class) {...}
```

An object lock

```
//doesn't matter what the lock object is as long as it's not null
private final Object lock = new Object(); 
...
synchronized (lock) {...} // will throw NPE if lock is null
```

They're both considered `object` locks because `String.class` returns an instance of `Class<String>`.

In the class lock, the thread acquires the `Class<String>` instance monitor. In the object lock, the thread acquires the `String` instance monitor.

Comment: @assylias You're right. I wanted to show that it doesn't matter what the object was, but didn't want to confuse with the word `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

> But according to java spec , all objects of same type(class) on heap share single Class object. So how can this be true for multi-thread synchronized access to Objects?

Only *synchronized* **static** methods would require a *thread* to acquire the *class* object's lock. All the *synchronized* instance methods would need the related instance object's lock which isn't shared.

Answer (score 1):

> But according to java spec , all objects of same type(class) on heap
>   share single Class object. So how can this be true for multi-thread
>   synchronized access to Objects?

Class level locks make more sense in static methods. If you use the synchronized keyword on a static method, the object whose monitor is used for the lock is the class object, i.e. the one represented by the literal Class.class.